# How to query the concrete table when only the parent table id is known

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have an inheritance relationship in my database, where I have a parent table (Table A) that is basically a sequence of auto-incrementing integers (Id column).  From here, I have several tables (Table B,C & D) that also have an Id column, which is a foreign key to the Id column in Table A.

Now my question is, if I have the Id, what is the most efficient way I can go about getting the correct row from table B, C, or D?

EDIT: There will be only ONE row with the Id in either table B, C, or D (there will not be a matching row in the other 2).

Comment: May I ask why you are storing data in random tables? You cannot have referential integrity in this model.

Comment: Per cdonner's comment, you may get a better response if you restate your question ... either you have an odd data model or its not clear what you are looking to do.

Comment: Thanks for the edit ... in that case the UNION example I provided would work if you're just looking to determine in which table the row exists.

Comment: For the casual reader - don't copy this model. If you have the same type of rows, put them all in one table. If you have different things with common attributes, store the common attributes in one table and the other data in separate tables, but make sure the references are constrained.

Comment: To clarify, the concrete tables don't have anything in common as far as attributes go.  However, I needed an identifier that was unique among all of the 3 tables.  This identifier was used in a "Comment" table where any one of the concrete tables could be commented upon.

Comment: The design description was vague because it wasn't really relevant to the question at hand, which may have been confusing to some, so I should have probably been a bit more specific.

Comment: Was your question answered though?  If not, revise the question and somebody would be happen to answer.  Otherwise you can accept an answer.  Welcome to SO BTW.

Answer (score 1):

You could use union queries ... i.e.:

```
select 'TABLE B', a_id from b where a_id = 1
UNION
select 'TABLE C', a_id from c where a_id = 1
UNION
select 'TABLE D', a_id from d where a_id = 1;
```

This would give you a list of tables with an a_id of 1, while also showing the table it resided in.

If all 3 tables have the same structure, you could do something similar:

```
select b.* from b where a_id = 1
UNION
select c.* from c where a_id = 1
UNION
select d.* from d where a_id = 1;
```